# Minimum-size Trie Construction by Dynamic Programming (War Story: What’s Past is Prolog from The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven S Skiena)

Tags: algorithm

I'm reading the The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven S Skiena, and trying to understand the solution to the problem of [War Story: What’s Past is Prolog](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBA77/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK2/NODE51.HTM).
The problem is also well described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/studying-skiena-war-story-what-s-past-is-prolog).

Basically, the problem is, given an ordered list of strings, give a optimal solution to construct a trie with minimum size (the string character as the node), with the constraint that the order of the strings must be reserved, while the character index can be reordered.

Maybe this is not an appropriate question here for stackoverflow, still I'm wondering if anyone could give me some hint on the solution, especially what this recurrence means by its arguments:
[the recurrence for the Dynamic Programming algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkW9j.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it this way:

1. Let's assume that we fix the index of the first character. All strings get split into `r` bins based on the value of the character in this position (bins are essentially subtrees).
2. We can work with each bin independently. It won't change the order across different bins because two strings in different bins are different in the first character.
3. Thus, we can solve the problem for each bin independently. After that, we need exactly one edge to connect the root to each bin (that is, subtree). That's where the formula
   `C[i_k, j_k] + 1` comes from.
4. As we want to minimize the total number of edges and we're free to pick the first position, we just try all possible options among `m` positions.

Note: this algorithm is correct under assumption that we can reorder the rest of the characters in each subtree independently. If it's not the case, the dynamic programming solution is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand your idea. But I'm stuck on the `C[i_k, j_k]`. Within the sub-run (bin), we need to pick the next best position to partition the sub-run to more runs. So without the knowledge of the previous position selected, we'll pick it again? And, as other typical DP algorithms, I suppose `C[i_k, j_k]` can be reused among different sub-runs, but how?

Comment: @user6502167 Yes, we pick them again and reuse the results.

Comment: Could you pls. explain it a little bit more? Or any pseudocode?